# Using a macro type argument inside a generated function

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to implement a macro which implements the Add trait for a struct, like so:

```
macro_rules! implement_add {
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl std::ops::Add for $t {
            type Output = $t;
            fn add(self, rhs: $t) -> $t {
                $t(self.0 + rhs.0)        // error on this line
            }
        }
    }
}

pub struct Length(f64);

implement_add!(Length);

fn main() {}
```

However, this gives an error on the indicated line:

```
<anon>:6:17: 6:19 error: unexpected token: `Length`
<anon>:6                 $t(self.0 + rhs.0)        // error on this line
                         ^~
```

This makes no sense to me. Especially since, if I replace `$t` there with `Length`, it compiles fine. Am I doing something wrong in my macro?

Playground: http://is.gd/EIEKub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've stumbled on a subtle bit of Rust's type system. `Length` is a type, but `Length()` is a *function*. These exist in different namespaces.

One work around is to extend your macro to accept a type **and** a function:

```
macro_rules! implement_add {
    ($t:ty, $c:ident) => {
        impl std::ops::Add for $t {
            type Output = $t;
            fn add(self, rhs: $t) -> $t {
                $c(self.0 + rhs.0)        // error on this line
            }
        }
    }
}

pub struct Length(f64);

implement_add!(Length, Length);

fn main() {}
```

Comment: @BenjaminLindley FWIW, you should probably do `ret.0 = ret.0 + rhs.0;` instead, since `+=` isn't generic yet, [so arbitrary addables fail](http://is.gd/ApfWLf).